# Remove anonymization in android log entries?

Tags: android

I see that some logs in android OS have a "personally identifiable information" safe guards that prevent such information from being leaked into log. For example, to remove the dialled phone number, as in the `placeOutgoingCall` method of the `CallsManager` class, you see calls to the `i` and `v` methods of the `Log` class which use `pii` and `piiHandle` methods to block leaks of private information in logs:

```
    if (gatewayInfo == null) {
        Log.i(this, "Creating a new outgoing call with handle: %s", Log.piiHandle(uriHandle));
    } else {
        Log.i(this, "Creating a new outgoing call with gateway handle: %s, original handle: %s",
                Log.pii(uriHandle), Log.pii(handle));
    }
```

Is there a way to overwrite the setting on the android OS classes, on a non-rooted device, such that when the `piiHandle` and `pii` methods above execute, while I am debugging my application, I can see the personally identifiable information (e.g. dialled phone number)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is by design so you can't snoop on user's private information. If there were a way to circumvent it in an intended way, the filter would make no sense anyway.

If you want to gather such information, you need to request the ACCESS_PHONE_STATE permission and get the phone number manually.

Comment: Ok. So I'd have to roll out my own version of the OS without the safeguards... Ugghhh.

Comment: @user8181050 Not of the OS. You need the app permission, then you can manually retrieve the calling phone number and log it yourself. What I meant is that you cannot modify the given CallsManager log handler.

Comment: Thanks... Well, I know what the number is (I registered as a listener of the OUTGOING_CALL_EVENT). But I am trying to get the OS to use my own gateway to dial out (like Google voice does) but it's not following my instructions, so I am just trying to troubleshoot what I am doing wrong by looking at the decisions the OS is making. Some of those decisions hinge on the data (e.g. phone number) I manipulate or not.